# Factor the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Factor the polynomial $X^3-X+1$ in $F_{23}$ and $X^3+X+1$ in $F_{31}$.

How can I know in which way to factor a polynomial mod $p$? Is there some specified method to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Cubics fall into three categories:

- irreducible
- product of a linear polynomial and an irreducible quadratic polynomial
- product of three linear polynomials (not necessarily distinct)

So just try all possible roots. If you don't find a root, it's irreducible.

If you find a root $a$, divide the polynomial by $X-a$ and search for the roots of the resulting quadratic, starting at $a$, because the roots may be repeated.

Comment: You may check your answers [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+X%5E3-X%2B1+mod+23) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+X%5E3%2BX%2B1+mod+31).

Comment: I think I found solution. $f=X^3+X+1$ has $-28$ for his root modulo $31$. Indeed, $(-28)^3-28+1 \equiv 0$ mod $31$. Because, discriminant of $f$ is $-31$, the only ramified prime is $23$. Since there will be a root of multiplicity at leas two, this will be a common root for $\overline{f}$ and its  derivative $\overline{f}'$. Mutiplying  $\overline{f}'$ with $X$, and $3\overline{f}- X\overline{f'}$, we get $2X+3 \equiv 0$ mod $31$, so $x \equiv -17 $ mod $31$. So $X^3+X+1 \equiv (X+17)^2(X+28)$ mod $31$.

Answer (score 3):

There is some "specified method" to factor polynomials $f(x)$ over finite fields, namely the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm). It gives
$$
x^3-x+1=(x + 10)^2(x + 3)
$$
over $\mathbb{F}_{23}$, and
$$
x^3+x+1=(x + 28)(x + 17)^2
$$
over $\mathbb{F}_{31}$.

Comment: Seeing that, simple squarefree factorization would also help.

Comment: Yes, indeed (more factorisation algorithms are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials)).

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of the polynomial $f(X)=X^3+aX+b$ is $\Delta = -4a^3-27b^2$. Consequently, for $f(X)=X^3-X+1$ we get $\Delta = -23$; for $f(X)=X^3+X+1$ we get $\Delta=-31$. In both cases, $\Delta\equiv0\pmod{p}$ where $p$ is the prime characteristic of the prescribed coefficient field.

A vanishing discriminant indicates repeated roots, not necessarily in the base field. (Over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, there are exceptions to this rule if $\deg f\geq p$, but that is not the case here.) The corresponding repeated factors of $f$ can be found by computing the [polynomial GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm) of $f$ with its first derivative $f'$. This is called [*square-free factorization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Square-free_factorization). Remember to use arithmetic $\bmod{p}$ when doing the calculations, and rescale the resulting polynomial GCD to be monic.

Since $f$ has degree $3$, dividing out the linear factor (found as GCD) squared leaves another linear factor; that is, $f$ splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_p$.